# Running minix 3 on VBox failed to load module

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, minix

I'm having problem with running minix_R3.2.1-972156d on Oracle VBox 4.3 on Windows 7.
"Warning 1 module failed to load" and it's probably the 13th one.
I had this problem once before on Ubuntu, and running Minix from bash using `VBoxSDL --startvm minix --norawr0 --norawr3 &` worked for me, so I'm just wondering whether there is any possibility to do it using Window's cmd.